# Why does batch.commit() not work until the WriteResult is called?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore database where I write data in a `WriteBatch()`.
So I encountered a strange behavior when commiting my changes.
My data is only updated or set if I do something with the variable of `batch.commit()`
The code should explain my problem better:

```
...
...
Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();       

Map<String, Foo> test = new HashMap<>();
test.put("Entry1", new Foo("Bar1", 5));
test.put("Entry2", new Foo("Bar2", 7));

WriteBatch batch = db.batch();
DocumentReference ref;

for (String key : test.keySet()) {
    ref = db.collection("foo").document(key);
    batch.set(ref, test.get(key), SetOptions.mergeFields("var1", "var2"));
}

// if I just call batch.commit() here data will not be overwritten on a change of i.e "Entry1"

// but if I call the next 2 lines everything is working as intended
ApiFuture<List<WriteResult>> result = batch.commit();
result.get();
```

I don't have a problem adding these lines in my code but I'm trying to understand why this is happening.

Comment: What do you mean through "I do something with the variable of batch.commit()"?

Comment: The last 2 lines of code in my example. If they are missing, changes won't be written to firestore. As I understand it should be irrelevant if I save the return value of batch.commit() or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your comment:

> The last 2 lines of code in my example. If they are missing, changes won't be written to firestore. As I understand it should be irrelevant if I save the return value of batch.commit() or not.

If those two lines of code are missing, more precisely the one with the `commit()`, nothing will happen since you aren't commiting anything to your batch. And yes, you're right, it doesn't matter if you are saving the result of `batch.commit()` to the `result` object or not, `commit()` method will always be called on that object. So the batch will be written in Firestore only when you call `commit()` on the batch object, otherwise the lines of code that exist before are useless.

Comment: yes but i call batch.commit in both cases. Either without saving as a variable or saving as WriteResult. Im confused because i commit the batch but only if save the variable of batch.commit() and do something with it the changes are actually comitted.

Comment: Yes, I understand you. In both cases you are calling `commit()` and in both cases `commit()` method is called. Doesn't matter if you save the result in a variable or not, that metod fires. What I think you don't understand is why the operation really happens when you use the `result.get()`. This is happening because once you save that result in variable, the `get()` method actually does the job since is trying to get the result from the `ApiFuture<List<WriteResult>>` object. Was I clear now?

Comment: Ok i understand now.I was just confused because the docs states that commit() applies the batch. This comment answers my question but I'm gonna mark your first reply as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @coolcool1994 I'm not familiar with Node.js, so you should ask a new question with that.